# Token list with line breaks for writing multiple lines to file

Tags: token-lists, write-file

I make use of a package (gnuplottex) that writes contents of an environment to a file, using the `\verbatim@start/processline/end` commands (by `\immediate\write\FileHandle{\the\verbatim@line}`). Now I want to modify the package to insert a couple of user-defined lines at the start of every file.

I defined a token list to store the lines and two commands to set these header lines:

```
\newtoks\headerlines
\def\setheaderlines#1{\headerlines{#1}}
\def\addtoheaderlines#1{\headerlines\expandafter{\the\headerlines#1}}
```

The tokens I then write to the file before the `\verbatim@start`, with `\immediate\write\FileHandle{\the\headerlines}`. This works fine for a single line, but I need to write several lines to the file, so preserve newlines in the token and write them to the files. Right now, this does not happen: everything gets put on a single line. How do I preserve newlines in the token list and write as separate lines to the file?

In other words:

```
\setheaderlines{header line 1
header line 2}
```

gets written to the file as

```
header line 1 header line 2`
```

instead of

```
header line 1
header line 2
```

Comment: `\setheaderlines{Line 1^^JLine2}` should do

Comment: Indeed, then the ^^J character is written as a line break to the file. However, I'd rather be able to \setheaderlines{Line 1
Line 2}. Isn't that somehow possible, too?

Comment: ^^ there's obviously supposed to be a line break between Line 1 and Line 2 there. Linebreaks.. ugh! ;)

Comment: @egreg This question is not explicitly duplicated. The token list from `\toks` register is written here, no macro body. It means that you cannot set `^^M` as active and to count on the expansion during `\ẅrite`. This expansion isn't done in toks register. Please, explain this to the other users they marked this as duplicate. The name "token list" is included in the title of this thread.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the `^^M` to the normal character when `\headerlines` are scanned. It means that token list includes `^^M` characters. Finally, you have to set this character as `\newlinechar` when this token list is printed.

```
\newtoks\headerlines

\def\setheaderlines{\headerlines={}\addtoheaderlines}
\def\addtoheaderlines{%
   \bgroup
   \catcode`\^^M=12
   \addtoheaderlinesA
}
\def\addtoheaderlinesA#1{\egroup\headerlines\expandafter{\the\headerlines#1}}

\def\addnltoheaderlines{\bgroup
   \lccode`X=`\^^M
   \lowercase{\egroup\headerlines\expandafter{\the\headerlines X}}%
}    
\def\writeheaderlines{%
   \bgroup
   \newlinechar=`\^^M
   \immediate\write16{\the\headerlines}%
   \egroup
}

Test:

\setheaderlines{%
line 1
line 2
}
\addtoheaderlines{%
line 3
line 4
}

\writeheaderlines
```

**Edit:** I've added the `\addtoheaderlines` macro and replaced the `\setheaderlines` macro to the special usage of `\addtoheaderlines`.

Comment: That does the trick. :) However, I'm still struggling with my `\addtoheaderlines`. Could you help me out there, too?

Comment: OK, I've upgraded my answer.

Comment: Cool, thanks. :) I don't understand why the `\egroup` is in its place, but it works. Does this group delimit the catcode change; and if so: why is it indeed before the `\headerlines` is set?

PS I've included a `^^J` right between `\the\headerlines` and `#1` so that a single line `\addtoheaderlines{line}` is added on its own line.

Comment: The processing is done in the following steps: `\bgroup`, catcode setting, scanning parameter, `\egroup`, `\headerlines` setting. The catcode have to be set when parameter is scanned.

Comment: ad. PS. I don't understand your `^^J` handling. My code uses `^^M` instead `^^J` as `\newlinechar`. There cannot be two `\newlinechars` at one time.

Comment: `\setheaderlines{line1}
\addtoheaderlines{line2}` leads to a single-line header with your macros. (Your example works because the initial `\setheaderlines` ends with a `^^M`.) To make sure `\addtoheaderlines` always starts a new line, I did exactly as I said, inserting `^^J` right before the `#1`. Using `^^M` there gives me an error.

Comment: OK, I've added the new macro `\addnltoheaderlines` to my example, which adds the new line symbol to the token list. You can use it in your other macros or you can add it to the `\addtoheaderlinesA` body between `\egroup` and `\headerlines`. It depends on the format of usage the `\addtoheaderlines`: with parameter in the isloated line or with parameter enclosed by braces.

Comment: By just *not* using token registers, but simply macros, the problem would be solved as in the question I linked as duplicate.

Comment: @egreg May be there is a reason for using token register. User needn't expand any token which is read, for example.